# How to apply survdiff to a list of dataframes

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survminer

I am trying to compare survival of all patients with a mutation in a gene to all patients without the mutation.
I have a list of 66 data frames for different batches of patients in different cancer types and I want to isolate the patients with the mutation and compare them against all other patients.

This is an example of the data frame

```r
A tibble:6 × 36

Sample ID           Start       End    mutation Patient ID     OS
TCGA-OR-A5J1-01 3   42265106    42265106    C-T TCGA-OR-A5J1    1   
OS.time
1355        
TCGA-OR-A5J2-01 X   39913284    39913284    C-A TCGA-OR-A5J2    1   1677
TCGA-OR-A5J3-01 17  10608472    10608472    G-A TCGA-OR-A5J3    0   2091
TCGA-OR-A5J3-01 17  10608472    10608472    G-A TCGA-OR-A5J3    0   2091
TCGA-OR-A5J4-01 5   38427121    38427121    G-C TCGA-OR-A5J4    1   423
TCGA-OR-A5J4-01 11  66272099    66272099    G-A TCGA-OR-A5J4    1   423
6 rows | 1-10, 33-36 of 36 columns
```

I want to get the log rank test and put it in a pdf with the title of the cancer type and gene name

this is the code I am running but it keeps saying it "Error: cannot find df1_OS"

```r
survdif_KM = function(x, y) { 
  #x is the name of your data.frame (cancer type)
  #y is you gene id you're interested in 
  read_file = paste0("C:/Users/cian/OneDrive/Desktop/Thesis/mergerd_data", 
                      "/", x)
  df <- read.table(read_file, sep = "\t", header=TRUE)
  df2 <- df[grep(y, df[[14]]), ] 
  df3 <- df[!grepl(y, df[[14]]), ]
  if (nrow(df2) > 20)
  {
  df4 <- df2[df2$X_PATIENT %in% df3$X_PATIENT, ]
  if(nrow(df4) > 0)
    {
      df3_1 <- df3[!df3$V5 %in% df2$V5, ]
      df3 <- df3_1
    }
  df2$group <- "A"
  df3$group <- "B" 
  df1_OS <- rbind(df2,df3)
  x = gsub("\\..*", "", x)
  name_of_file = paste("Log-Rank", "Test", x, y, sep="_")
  surv_diff <- survdiff(Surv(OS.time, OS) ~ group, data = df1_OS)
  pval_sav <- surv_pvalue(surv_diff)
  if (pval_sav$pval >= 0.05)
  {
  filename= paste0('C:/Users/cian/OneDrive/Desktop/Thesis/tables/', 
                     name_of_file, ".pdf", sep="")
  pdf(filename)
  a <- surv_diff
  print(a)
  dev.off()
    }}}
```

as requested the head(df). The only columns of note are V5, V1, V2 V3, V4, X_PATIENT OS and OS.time

```r
                   V5    V1       V2       V3  V4    V6     V7   V8       V9      V10 V11 V12 V13
1 TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A chr15 44536637 44536637 G-A chr15 HAVANA exon 44536166 44536681  NA   -  NA
2 TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A chr15 44536637 44536637 G-A chr15 HAVANA exon 44536043 44536933  NA   -  NA
3 TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A chr15 44536637 44536637 G-A chr15 HAVANA exon 44535760 44536913  NA   -  NA
4 TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A chr15 44536637 44536637 G-A chr15 HAVANA exon 44536043 44536640  NA   -  NA
5 TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A chr15 99131259 99131259 G-A chr15 HAVANA exon 99130803 99131806  NA   -  NA
6 TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A chr17 74261981 74261981 C-T chr17 HAVANA exon 74261589 74262020  NA   -  NA
          gene_ID                  transcript_ID         gene_type                  gene_name
1 ENSG00000179523  transcript_id ENST00000702400  gene_type lncRNA         gene_name EIF3J-DT
2 ENSG00000179523  transcript_id ENST00000313807  gene_type lncRNA         gene_name EIF3J-DT
3 ENSG00000179523  transcript_id ENST00000657789  gene_type lncRNA         gene_name EIF3J-DT
4 ENSG00000179523  transcript_id ENST00000560750  gene_type lncRNA         gene_name EIF3J-DT
5 ENSG00000261054  transcript_id ENST00000566974  gene_type lncRNA         gene_name SYNM-AS2
6 ENSG00000264272  transcript_id ENST00000583018  gene_type lncRNA  gene_name ENSG00000264272
          transcript_type                  transcript_name    exon_number                  exon_ID    level
1  transcript_type lncRNA     transcript_name EIF3J-DT-208  exon_number 1  exon_id ENSE00003985681  level 2
2  transcript_type lncRNA     transcript_name EIF3J-DT-201  exon_number 1  exon_id ENSE00001213385  level 2
3  transcript_type lncRNA     transcript_name EIF3J-DT-207  exon_number 1  exon_id ENSE00003985691  level 2
4  transcript_type lncRNA     transcript_name EIF3J-DT-205  exon_number 1  exon_id ENSE00002562703  level 2
5  transcript_type lncRNA     transcript_name SYNM-AS2-201  exon_number 1  exon_id ENSE00002601413  level 2
6  transcript_type lncRNA  transcript_name ENST00000583018  exon_number 1  exon_id ENSE00002709179  level 2
                         tag1                tag2                     havana_gene
1          hgnc_id HGNC:48616          tag TAGENE  havana_gene OTTHUMG00000171875
2  transcript_support_level 1  hgnc_id HGNC:48616                       tag basic
3          hgnc_id HGNC:48616          tag TAGENE  havana_gene OTTHUMG00000171875
4  transcript_support_level 3  hgnc_id HGNC:48616                       tag basic
5  transcript_support_level 2  hgnc_id HGNC:56228                       tag basic
6  transcript_support_level 3           tag basic           tag Ensembl_canonical
                      havana_transcript OS    X_PATIENT OS.time
1                                        0 TCGA-2E-A9G8    1249
2                            tag TAGENE  0 TCGA-2E-A9G8    1249
3  havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000526744  0 TCGA-2E-A9G8    1249
4                 tag Ensembl_canonical  0 TCGA-2E-A9G8    1249
5                 tag Ensembl_canonical  0 TCGA-2E-A9G8    1249
6        havana_gene OTTHUMG00000178577  0 TCGA-2E-A9G8    1249
```

This is an example of an x and y with x being the name of the dataframe and Y being the gene

```r
x = "UCEC_TCGA_ms.txt"
y = "ENSG00000240498"
```

I am running the loop using `mapply` on a crossed list of all the dataframes and genes.

I have already done a very similar function to get kaplan-meier curves using the `survfit` function but that also did not work until I changed the survfit function to surv_fit. I tried this with survdiff but it did not work.

Is there another type of survdiff I can use like in survfit that will run over a list of dataframes?

the example with survfit is attached below for reference as a function that did work

```r
new_create_KM = function(x, y) { 
  #x is the name of your data.frame (cancer type)
  #y is you gene id you're interested in 
  read_file = paste0("C:/Users/cian/OneDrive/Desktop/Thesis/mergerd_data", 
                     "/", x)
  df <- read.table(read_file, sep = "\t", header=TRUE)
  df2 <- df[grep(y, df[[14]]), ] 
  df3 <- df[!grepl(y, df[[14]]), ]
  if (nrow(df2) > 150)
  {
    df4 <- df2[df2$X_PATIENT %in% df3$X_PATIENT, ]
    if(nrow(df4) > 0)
    {
      df3_1 <- df3[!df3$V5 %in% df2$V5, ]
      df3 <- df3_1
    }
    df2$group <- "A"
    df3$group <- "B" 
    df1_OS <- rbind(df2,df3)
    x = gsub("\\..*", "", x)
    name_of_file = paste("KM", "Curve", x, y, sep="_")
    survival_function <- surv_fit(Surv(df1_OS$OS.time, df1_OS$OS)~group, 
                                  data=df1_OS) 
    pval_sav <- surv_pvalue(survival_function)
    if (pval_sav$pval <= 0.05)
    {
      filename= paste0('C:/Users/cian/OneDrive/Desktop/Thesis/Graphs2/', 
                        name_of_file, ".pdf", sep="")
      # I changed destination to graphs 2 so I could use the new all_genes
      pdf(filename)
      a <- ggsurvplot(survival_function, conf.int=TRUE, pval=TRUE, 
                      risk.table=TRUE, 
                      legend.labs=c("mutation", "no mutation"), 
                      legend.title="lncRNA status", 
                      palette=c("orangered1", "royalblue"), 
       title=name_of_file) 
      print(a)
      dev.off()
    }}}
```

### Edit by @jared_mamrot

I'm not sure if this is enough data to reproduce the problem, but here is a `dput()` of the `head(df)` above:

```r
structure(list(rn = c("TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A", "TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A", 
"TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A", "TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A", "TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A", "TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A"
), V5 = c("chr15", "chr15", "chr15", "chr15", "chr15", "chr17"
), V1 = c(44536637L, 44536637L, 44536637L, 44536637L, 99131259L, 
74261981L), V2 = c(44536637L, 44536637L, 44536637L, 44536637L, 
99131259L, 74261981L), V3 = c("G-A", "G-A", "G-A", "G-A", "G-A", 
"C-T"), V4 = c("chr15", "chr15", "chr15", "chr15", "chr15", "chr17"
), V6 = c("HAVANA", "HAVANA", "HAVANA", "HAVANA", "HAVANA", "HAVANA"
), V7 = c("exon", "exon", "exon", "exon", "exon", "exon"), V8 = c(44536166L, 
44536043L, 44535760L, 44536043L, 99130803L, 74261589L), V9 = c(44536681L, 
44536933L, 44536913L, 44536640L, 99131806L, 74262020L), V10 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V11 = c("-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), V12 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V13 = c("ENSG00000179523", "ENSG00000179523", 
"ENSG00000179523", "ENSG00000179523", "ENSG00000261054", "ENSG00000264272"
), gene_ID = c("transcript_id", "transcript_id", "transcript_id", 
"transcript_id", "transcript_id", "transcript_id"), transcript_ID = c("ENST00000702400", 
"ENST00000313807", "ENST00000657789", "ENST00000560750", "ENST00000566974", 
"ENST00000583018"), gene_type = c("gene_type", "gene_type", "gene_type", 
"gene_type", "gene_type", "gene_type"), gene_name = c("lncRNA", 
"lncRNA", "lncRNA", "lncRNA", "lncRNA", "lncRNA"), NA. = c("gene_name", 
"gene_name", "gene_name", "gene_name", "gene_name", "gene_name"
), NA..1 = c("EIF3J-DT", "EIF3J-DT", "EIF3J-DT", "EIF3J-DT", 
"SYNM-AS2", "ENSG00000264272"), OS = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L
), X_PATIENT = c("TCGA-2E-A9G8", "TCGA-2E-A9G8", "TCGA-2E-A9G9", 
"TCGA-2E-A9G9", "TCGA-2E-A9G1", "TCGA-2E-A9G9"), OS.time = c(1249L, 
1249L, 999L, 999L, 1300L, 1300L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Is there a typo in "C:/Users/cian/OneDrive/Desktop/Thesis/mergerd_data"? I.e. should "mergerd_data" be "merged_data"?

Comment: That is not a typo, that is the file name. I must have typed the filename incorrectly when I made it but the file is called mergerd_data.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the headings for the example data frame are "Sample ID", "Chromsome no.", "start site", "end site", "reference nucleotide-mutation", "Patient ID", "Overall survival (1=died, 0= did not die)", "Survival time"

Comment: Are you able to please edit your post to include the output from `dput(head(df))`?

Comment: @jared_mamrot I have added in the head(df) let me know if you need any other information

Comment: What was requested was the `dput(head(df))` and not the `head(df)` the two are different

Comment: Hi @onyambu, if you could please take a look at this problem (despite head(df) being used instead of dput(df)) I would appreciate it and happily award you the bounty. I wasn't able to figure it out, but it seems 'solvable'. Thanks, Jared

Comment: The problem is we cannot reproduce your data without the output from `dput(head(df))` Note that we need the data in R, we can only do that by copy pasting the `dput(head(df))` and not `head(df)`

Comment: Yes, I understand, it's not my question - I have edited the post to include the `dput(df)` of the `head(df)` that was posted. Thanks @onyambu